# How to reuse subprocess

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

There's a Windows Python application.
The application must gather several data about network configuration to build internal data structures.
The process takes now 10 seconds, making it barely usable.
Those 10 seconds are spent on creating separate subprocesses, which call powershell to get the data.
I think process creation is heavy on windows, so wanted to reuse single process to see if it makes a difference.
I'm using code similar to:

```
    if not ps:
        ps = sp.Popen([conf.prog.powershell],
                  stdout=sp.PIPE,
                  stdin=sp.PIPE,
                  universal_newlines=True)
```

And later:

```
        ps.stdin.write(' '.join(cmd + ['|', 'select %s' % ', '.join(fields), '|', 'fl', '\n']))
        # ... ps.stdout.read()/readline()
```

It hangs, so I've searched for alternatives.

They were:

1. Use communicate in subprocess to avoid any deadlocks - I can't do that, because communicate waits for the process to finish and I don't want the process to finish.
2. Use pexpect, but it's not fully functional on Windows and by using it powershell console took over python console.
3. Use own threads for read/write (inspired by http://eyalarubas.com/python-subproc-nonblock.html) - subsequent commands sent to subprocess instance didn't cause any action.

I couldn't find any Python library to not use processes to get powershell data (COM?) other than reading registry.
The libraries I found (netifaces, psutil) didn't offer the requested functionality.

So, does anybody have a working code example for the mentioned case (or can provide alternative way to get the information)?

Python 2.7, but I don't think it matters

OS: Win7/Win10

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Usually the creation of python subpresses dont take so long. You may want describe what you are doing in Powershell. Did you try to gather the data through other sources (wmi, winapi, ...) ?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.

I have profiled it further and it seems that there are 141 PowerShell queries, resulting in 6 s execution time.

This is not my application - it's scapy (https://github.com/secdev/scapy) and everybody can see the delay just by executing:

    from scapy import all as scapy

on Windows 7/WIndows 10 machine.

This is not my code, so I'm trying to avoid massive refactoring and, as I wrote, I couldn't get the data from other sources. I can provide the exact list of queries, if needed.

For now I'll try to see if any caching makes a difference.

Robert

Comment: After implementing some caching it seems that in fact process creation isn't the culprit.
Still, I'd like to see the working solution for the case given :)